# How to print sign "-" instead of "." using <ol>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use the HTML code:

```html
<ol>
  <li>first item</li>
  <li>second item</li>
  <li>third item</li>
</ol>
```

How can I print sign "-" instead of dot using OL HTML tag
like example:

```
1 - first item
2 - second item
3 - third item
```

How can I implement it in HTML format.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the help section on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
    content: counter(item) " - "; 
    counter-increment: item 
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ol>
```

This will work in IE8+ and other browsers

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I tried it doesn't work. Below is the output:                                                              ol { counter-reset: item; list-style-type: none; } li:before { content: counter(item) " - "; counter-increment: item }
1. one
2. two

Comment: @Levintovich, perhaps the style is overwritten in the other place.